# How to decode $Token on AWS CDK output

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

For AWS CDK that creating any recourse in the output will be encoded to  `${Token[TOKEN.NUM]}`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tokens.html

e.g. on below output how could I decode/re-map the region in Type Script?

```
PrivateSubnet {
    node: ConstructNode { host: [Circular], _actualNode: [Node] },
    stack: Stack {
      node: [ConstructNode],
      _missingContext: [],
      _stackDependencies: {},
      templateOptions: {},
      _logicalIds: [LogicalIDs],
      account: '************',
      region: '${Token[AWS.Region.8]}',
      environment: 'aws://************/unknown-region',
      terminationProtection: undefined,
      _stackName: 'CreateVpcStack',
      tags: [TagManager],
      artifactId: 'CreateVpcStack',
      templateFile: 'CreateVpcStack.template.json',
      _versionReportingEnabled: true,
      synthesizer: [LegacyStackSynthesizer],
      [Symbol(@aws-cdk/core.DependableTrait)]: [Object]
    },
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68448446/16442705

Comment: I'm guessing it's not possible to do this.  However, I strongly recommend opening an issue on the GitHub repo asking for hints: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk

Comment: Thanks @Hcaertnit, seem I am not the only one facing this issue

Comment: Nope.  I'd say it's actually a common problem that people encounter, but I wasn't really able to find an issue that confirmed my theory.

Comment: This is impossible in principle, because the tokens are evaluated at deploy time, not at synth time. This stack seems to be environment-agnostic, so the Region value will depend on which account and region it is deployed to. Evaluating that before deployment is impossible.